# How do I connect my Mid-2010 iMac to my Late 2015 Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, displayport, thunderbolt-display

I mistook the mini Display Port (mDP) behind my iMac to mean it was a Thunderbolt port. The <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> does not work when both ends are Thunderbolt for my setup.

Please suggest what cables to buy.

Edit: This is 27 inch iMac
 Model Identifier: iMac11,3

Comment: Which iMac do you have specifically?  Please issue the command `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep -i identifier` in Terminal and post the results to your original question.

Comment: Added  Model Identifier: iMac11,3

Comment: Thanks.  That info is super important to make sure we are giving you an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a 27 inch iMac (Mid 2010) then you need a [mini DisplayPort to mini DisplayPort cable](http://radnex.us/Cable_matters_mdp-to-mdp_cable).

According to Apple's Support Page, [Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592), you can accomplish this with the cable referenced above, but only with a 27" iMac if you are using the Mid 2010 model. The other option is to use a [Thunderbolt cable](http://radnex.us/apple_thunderbolt_1_and_2_cable) which is backward compatible with the mDP to mDP cable. Thunderbolt uses the same connector as the mDP cable, but exta signaling for PCIe, USB and mDP

[image: system requirements]

Comment: Do I need an mDP to ThunderBolt cable too - my MBP does not have a mDP port. It has two Thunderbolt ports instead.

Comment: No.  mDP to mDP per Apple.  A Thunderbolt port is a combination of mDP **and** PCIe.

Comment: So one end of the new mDP cable will connect to the iMac and the other end will also fit into the Thunderbolt port on my MBP?

Comment: Correct.  mDP and TB use the same connector.  I wrote a primer on TB [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228892/119271).