# How to connect an iMac 21.7 inch 2009 as a monitor to a MacBook Pro late 2013

Tags: macbook-pro, imac

I’m trying to use my iMac 2009 as a second monitor for my MacBook Pro 2013 but can’t work out how to connect. Any ideas? My MacBook Pro doesn’t have a Mini DisplayPort.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-an-imac-as-a-display-mh30822/mac

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

Only the 27" iMac's from 2009 were able to use Target Display Mode via mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt

- [How do I connect my Mid-2010 iMac to my Late 2015 Macbook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/243542/119271)
- [Use your iMac as a display with target display mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)